# Como converter DDMMAAAA para DD/MM/AAAA em C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// tetando ex 01 

int main(){
 int dia,mes,ano, data;
  printf("Digite a data em DDMMAAA: ");
  scanf("%d", &data );
  
  dia= data/1000000;
  printf("%d", dia);
 
  
}
```

Não consigo desenvolver a lógica para separa mes e ano do formato DDMMAAA alguém pode me dar alguma dica, procurei na mátematica também pra entender se existia alguma formula mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Por que está capturando a data num `int`? Isso claramente é um caso de para captura-la num `char[9]` e então manipular a string, a menos que isso faça parte de um desafio, o que você está fazendo não faz sentido.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer utilizando apenas matemática:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int data;
    printf("Digite a data em DDMMAAAA: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
  
    int dia = (data / 1000000) % 100;
    int mes = (data / 10000) % 100;
    int ano = data % 10000;
    printf("A data em DD/MM/AAAA é %02d/%02d/%04d.\n", dia, mes, ano);
}
```

Leia

- `data` dividido por 10ⁿ como "retorne `data` sem os últimos **n** dígitos"; e
- `data` módulo 10ⁿ como "retorne `data` apenas com os últimos **n** dígitos".

Assumindo que o valor inserido pelo usuário foi `01082021`, no caso do `mes`, por exemplo: quando faço `01082021 / 10000`, digo para remover os últimos quatro dígitos de `01082021`, ficando `0108`. Em  seguida, quando faço `0108 % 100`, digo para manter os últimos dois dígitos de `0108`, ficando `08`, que é o mês da data inserida.

---

Ou, [como o @user140828 notou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/521634/como-converter-ddmmaaaa-para-dd-mm-aaaa-em-c#comment948893_521634) porém não detalhou, armazenar em um `char[9]`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char data[9];
    printf("Digite a data em DDMMAAAA: ");
    scanf("%s", data);
    
    char dia[3]; strncpy(dia, data, 2); dia[2] = '\0';
    char mes[3]; strncpy(mes, data + 2, 2); mes[2] = '\0';
    char ano[5]; strncpy(ano, data + 4, 4); ano[4] = '\0';
    printf("A data em DD/MM/AAAA é %s/%s/%s.\n", dia, mes, ano);
}
```

No entanto, o dia, mês e ano ficarão como strings. Caso você queira transformá-los para inteiros para manipulá-los depois, use a função `atoi`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char data[9];
    printf("Digite a data em DDMMAAAA: ");
    scanf("%s", data);
    
    char diaStr[3]; strncpy(diaStr, data, 2); diaStr[2] = '\0';
    char mesStr[3]; strncpy(mesStr, data + 2, 2); mesStr[2] = '\0';
    char anoStr[5]; strncpy(anoStr, data + 4, 4); anoStr[4] = '\0';
    
    int dia = atoi(diaStr);
    int mes = atoi(mesStr);
    int ano = atoi(anoStr);
    printf("A data em DD/MM/AAAA é %02d/%02d/%04d.\n", dia, mes, ano);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! ficou bem claro na explicação, eu buguei tanto que não consegui pensar em utilizar modulo, era tão simples kkkkk dscp a pergunta meio boba e  novamente agradeço pela ajuda e pela explicação.